# React Native Audio send voice note to backend

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I have a chat screen from which I want to send voice note to the backend using `react-native-audio` and play it using `react-native-sound`.

The problem I am having is in the recording of the voice note, the Readme in the `react-native-audio` isn't that clear so I guess there is something wrong with my implementation.

Here is my render method

```
render() {

    return (

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={ this.start_timer }>
                <Icon name="microphone-outline" type="MaterialCommunityIcons" style={ styles.microphone_icon } />
        </TouchableOpacity>

        {
             this.state.is_recording

             ? <View style={ styles.recorder_container }>

                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={ this.clear_time }>
                      <Icon name="ios-trash" type="Ionicons" style={ styles.trash_icon } />
                  </TouchableOpacity>

                  <Text style={ styles.timer }>{ this.state.count_up.format('mm:ss') }</Text>

                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={ this.send }>
                      <Icon name="md-send" type="Ionicons" style={ styles.send_icon } />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
               </View>

            : null
        }
    )
}
```

and here are the functions to record and send

```
start_timer = () => {

this.setState({ is_recording: true })

let audioPath = AudioUtils.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/test.aac';

this.audio = AudioRecorder.prepareRecordingAtPath(audioPath, {
  SampleRate: 22050,
  Channels: 1,
  AudioQuality: "Low",
  AudioEncoding: "aac"
});

this.setState({ audio: audioPath })

this.interval = setInterval(() => this.setState(prev => ({ count_up: prev.count_up.add(1, 'second') })), 1000)

}

send = async () => {

await AudioRecorder.stopRecording();

this.setState({ is_recording: false })

AudioRecorder.onFinished = async (data) => {

  let fd = new FormData();

  await fd.append('file', data.audioFileURL)

  let sound = await Api.post('api/chats/upload-vc', fd)

 }

}

clear_time = () => {

this.setState({ is_recording: false, count_up: moment().minute(0).second(0) })

clearInterval(this.interval)

}
```

I logged the file in the backend function but I keep getting an empty array
so what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

I fixed my audio PLAYER following this tip from 2016: https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound/issues/20#issuecomment-205683378
And to `POST` your file to a server remember to add `file://` before your path like `"file:///data/user/0/bla.bla/files/1695695e-aaaa-4e0b-9b57-998cb6b50608.aac"`. The size still appears to be 0 kb on Android `Finished recording` but it works!
I'm saving in `AudioUtils.DocumentDirectoryPath` atm

Answer (score 1):

In your form data are you passing:

```
AudioUtils.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/test.aac'
```

as the path of the file? it's a bit unclear with your current snippet.

Also, checkout this example
https://github.com/jsierles/react-native-audio/blob/master/AudioExample/AudioExample.js

Comment: no, i'm passing the `data.audioFileURL` on the `AudioRecorder.onFinished` callback, am i supposed to pass on the `AudioUtils.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/test.aac'` ?

Comment: What about the data.audioFileURL ? When i logged it i saw a path like 'file://somepath'

Comment: I faced a similar issue, it worked for me. Also, make sure you're passing the reference of the file and not the location in the string format.

Comment: How's that ? Sorry i'm kind of a beginner .. :(

Comment: https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs

look into this library, this can help.

Comment: last question, i could test it on simulator right ?

Comment: still getting an empty array .. , what about the reference thing ? could you please tell me how to do it ?

Comment: there is something wrong with the recording i just followed the path in my device and found the file 'test.aac', it's size is 0kb ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184631/discussion-between-abdul-elah-js-and-anurag145).